# Large Icon over control buttons - terminal Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: icons, gnome-terminal, titlebar, window-buttons, numix

Currently I'm facing a bug in which a big icon is over my control buttons in the terminal display. This is happening when I use as a theme application **Mojave-dark** and **Numix-circle**. When I put the theme that came by default on ubuntu, it's fine.
[Click to see bug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kNFX.png)

I have try

```
sudo apt install gnome-icon-theme # fixes
sudo apt purge gnome-icon-theme # breaks
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-extras
```

None of them works, can someone help me please

Comment: The upstream bug is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1770507. Nag the developers there, or recompile mutter for yourself without the offending patch.